# The Ubuntu can't run into logon or desktop when it is starting up

Tags: startup

I installed Ubuntu 20 and run for half a year, which works absolutely all right. However, last week it suddenly broke down.

Generally during the startup, Ubuntu should demonstrate a logo before jumping to the logon screen or desktop directly if only single user exists. Nevertheless, my OS stuck at that ubuntu logo forever with a mouse arrow at the lower right corner which is movable to the whole screen but the rest of the screen is dark. I tried to wait but hours after hours it stayed same. I tried again and again but everyday it just stops there. It is not dead lock because when I press the power button to turn it off by force, it would quit that screen and go into text interface shortly before powering off.

I tried the memory and hardware test using the self testing tool of my PC and it passed. But it was obstructed in 58% endlessly during the memory test using Ubuntu self testing tool in the startup menu.

I don't want to install a fresh system again because the documents in the home directory are crucial to me.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIsx.jpg)

Comment: I have corrected your formatting and made your image viewable. As others request more information, [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1303017/edit) to add new information. Do not add new information in comments.

Comment: Depending on the distribution you can hit Esc key or Tab key to see the logs.  The screen may show you what is stopping the install.  As suggested in the answer below mostly likely you have a failing hard disk.

Comment: If your grub memory test freezes at 58% then you need to fix your RAM.

Answer (score 1):

If your documents in /home are valuable to you, then you should back them up now BEFORE attempting any repair.

- Use a different (working) system to create a new LiveUSB installer.
- Boot from the USB installer, and enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment.
- Mount your HDD and copy your critical files to some other media where they will be safe and accessible even if your repair fails.

After your data is backed up , THEN you are ready to start attempting repair.

Comment: I am sorry but your suggestion can not make me backup my files under /home directory such as folder Documents and Downloads which cannot be found as directories on HDD.

Comment: If they are not found, then your HDD seems not mounted. Look up how to mount it.

Comment: My current Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS AMD64, I have just burned an 20.10 AMD64 image and will have a try according to what you said above. I hope everything could be solved by just selecting "upgrade the system" command in the 20.10 interface, otherwise I have to install a fresh system.